# appengine data nucleus enhancer issue with classes not getting enhanced

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have a appengine web app that keeps giving me a class not enhanced error...  Whenever I try to log into the app from the login page I get the following error

Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for class com.d.su.model.Resource but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.

i've googled quite a bit and it seems to be an issue with data nucleus enhancer not running on all classes.  i;m using eclipse with the google plugin, I tried it on two different versions of the appengine SDK but no luck...  Any idea how I can go about resolving this?

Comment: When you 'clean' your project, do you get a "Datanucleus Enhancer compleated with succes (...)" in your Console (Datanucleus Enhancement)? Are your getting an error?. 
Is your ORM path correct? (Project > Properties > Google > App Engine > ORM)

Comment: No I don't see any data nucleus reference when I clean my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes while changing app engine sdk, jars are not completely removed from previous version, so check if your webapps/lib have same jars of multiple version if so then delete all jars from webapps/lib then change appengine version.

Clean and refresh project, make sure lib have only default jars